# Can I listen to changes in the activity stack

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-manager

It has been asked before but never got an answer: I want to know when a certain 3rd party activity (the browser) is in the foreground and when it is not in the foreground anymore. I know how to check which activity is in the foreground, but how do I listen to changes in the activity stack.

Any other idea is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any events broadcast that you could listen for. The only way to do this would be to continuously monitor the foreground task using `ActivityManager.getRunningTasks()` and check for changes in `topActivity` in the foreground task.